# Electret mic - power source noise

Tags: power-supply, filter, electret

I'm working on a project that requires connecting an electret mic to an STM32 nucleo board. The mic is on a amplifier board with the following specs:

MAX4466 microphone breakout board; You can set the gain from 25x to 125x

Parameters: power supply voltage: +2.4V to +5.5V. Power supply rejection ratio: 112dB; Common mode rejection ratio: 126dB; AVOL: 125dB (RL = 100kΩ) rail-to-rail output; Quiescent power supply current: <24μA; Gain bandwidth: 600kHz

It will need to be powered by the same +5V from the USB that will power the MCU and an OLED display. When I connect the Vcc of the mic board to a USB port +5v , instead of a flatline signal with no audio, I get the signals below. Vpp is pretty significant. As a test, I powered the mic board with +5v from a 9V battery + one of those cheap DC-DC converter boards board, and the signal is almost perfectly flat with no audio input - around 100mV pp, which is fine for my application. I'm assuming I need some sort of circuit to condition the +5V USB to feed into the mic board? I tried using the DC-DC converter, feeding in the +5V from the USB, and still get noise almost to 1V, which is not acceptable. Is there some other simple filter circuit I can use?  What about a Pi filter?  thanks
[image]

Comment: This sounds awfully familiar. In addition to using USB for power, are you by any chanse using USB also for data transmission?

Comment: @Justme no. just for the power.  Yeas the "noise" really does not look like random noise.

Comment: But if you connect it to a computer with USB, isn't the USB used for the ST-Link programming interface? Or are you powering it with non-data device like mobile charger or powerbank?

Comment: powering with a usb charger after the mcu is programmed.  I tried powering from the usb charger, and it has better performance but still some noise around 800mv PP

Comment: Sounds like 4th harmonic of 50 Hz CM noise.  And needs shielding and RF grounding to PE.